# 一度phpでINSERT文を実行してしまうと、別の値でのINSERTが実行できなくなります。

Tags: php, mysql

以下のwhileでPOSTで同じサイトに飛ばして、GETしたpidをカートに追加していくというシステムなのですが、Mysqlのcartテーブルに何も無い状態ならINSERT文がうまくいくのですが、一つでもデータがすでに入っているとINSERTがうまくいきません。

Mysql上の設定の問題だと思いますが、何が問題なのか教えていただけると幸いです。

以下はソースコードです

```
$re=$s->query("SELECT id,title,description,price,date_created FROM thread LIMIT $index,$perPage");
while($kekka=$re->fetch()){
    <a href="keizi.php?gu=$kekka[0]">$kekka[0] $kekka[1]</a><br><br>
    <div>DESCRIPTION<br>$kekka[2]</div><br>
    商品価格:$kekka[3]
    <br>
    $kekka[4]作成<br>
    <form method="GET" action="keizi_top.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value=$kekka[0]/>
    <div><input type="submit" value="カートに追加"><br><br></div>
    </form>
}
```

Comment: cartテーブルの定義やINSERT文がどう書かれているか判らないと、アドバイスしようがないと思います。差し支えない範囲で開示できませんか？

Comment: 問題を再現できるコードと、「うまくいかない」の具体的な内容を質問を編集して追記してください